# Is std::span constructor missing noexcept?

Tags: c++, exception, stl, noexcept

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span) constructor (2) of `std::span` is defined as

```c++
template< class It >
explicit(extent != std::dynamic_extent)
constexpr span( It first, size_type count );
```

with its exceptions listed as `2) Throws nothing.`

If this constructor "throws nothing" then why is it even listed under exceptions and why is the constructor not marked noexcept?

Comment: `std::span` is not part of STL, it is in the standard library, [tag:std].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because this constructor has preconditions. From [the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/span.cons):

> `template<class It>`
>   `constexpr explicit(extent != dynamic_extent) span(It first, size_type count);`
>
> Constraints: Let U be remove_­reference_­t<iter_­reference_­t>.
>
> - It satisfies contiguous_­iterator.
> - is_­convertible_­v<U(*)[], element_­type(*)[]> is true.
>   [Note 1: The intent is to allow only qualification conversions of the iterator reference type to element_­type.
>   — end note]
>
> Preconditions:
>
> - [first, first + count) is a valid range.
> - It models contiguous_­iterator.
> - If extent is not equal to dynamic_­extent, then count is equal to extent.
>
> Effects: Initializes data_­ with to_­address(first) and size_­ with count.
>
> Throws: Nothing.

Functions with preconditions that "throw nothing" aren't marked `noexcept` because undefined behavior can occur if these preconditions aren't fulfilled. For example, [`std::vector::front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front) isn't marked `noexcept` even though there is no way it would throw, but calling it on an empty vector is undefined behavior.

Here is a paper about it: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1656r1.html

Comment: Unless I am mistaken that paper is arguing that the standard should be changed so that these narrow contract functions would be marked noexcept.

Comment: @Chris_F Yes, but it also explains why the current situation is what it is. Standardization takes time.